# Wordpress website: how do I align a search box with other navigation menu items?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have [this website i'm working on](http://crazzzytravel.com) and I want to align the search box in main menu (near 'About Us') to all the other items in the menu, ATM it moved down for some reason. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of linking to your site, you should paste the relevant code here and make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). This way, if someone stumbles upon this question later on and you've changed your layout or the website isn't even up anymore, they will still be able to see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use vertical-align: top in your li css

```
#masthead nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and adjust the search form accordingly

```
#searchform {
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

hope this will solve your issue.